# R - iGraph does not plot ("invalid RGB specification")

Tags: r, plot, colors, transparency, igraph

I am trying to visualize a large network with 2 types of nodes (investors making investments into companies). To increase the visibility I want to color the edges according to the node they are ending in.

```
edge.end <- get.edges(g, 1:ecount(g))[,1] # g is my igraph element
E(g)$color <- V(g)$color[edge.end] # edge color based on vector color
```

This works perfectly and returns 32,000+ hex color codes.

```
[1] "#FFF5F0" "#FFF5F0" "#FFF5F0" ...
```

As the graph is now extremely crowded I want to make the edges transparent based on their respective investment size. The transparency should be between 0.5 and 1.
For this I use GISTools:

```
E(g)$color <- add.alpha(E(g)$color, ((0.5*(E(g)$Invested.Amount.in.EUR - min(E(g)$Invested.Amount.in.EUR))) / (max(E(g)$Invested.Amount.in.EUR)-min(E(g)$Invested.Amount.in.EUR)))+0.5)
```

This appears to work and returns:

```
[1] "#FFF5F0BF" "#FFF5F0B3" "#FFF5F099" ...
```

However, when I plot now the graph with the following code (which worked perfectly before adding the transparency)

```
pdf('all.pdf')
plot(g, layout = layout_with_fr(g, niter = 1000, weights = E(g)$width))
dev.off()
```

R returns the following error:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  invalid RGB specification
```

If I just overwrite the E(g)$color with, e.g., "#63636309" it works perfectly... 
Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this?

Thanks a lot,
Jan

Comment: Can you provide a small code snippet with data that is reproducible? It's unclear to me which color is throwing the error.

Comment: It appears to be a problem in the GISTools package. I am using now the scales package with the following formula
`E(g)$color <- alpha(E(g)$color, ((0.8*(E(g)$Invested.Amount.in.EUR - min(E(g)$Invested.Amount.in.EUR))) / (max(E(g)$Invested.Amount.in.EUR)-min(E(g)$Invested.Amount.in.EUR)))+0.2)` and it works smoothly!

Comment: Please consider posting your comment response as an answer to your question; or consider deleting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a problem in the GISTools package. I am using now the scales package with the following formula

```
E(g)$color <- alpha(E(g)$color, ((0.8*(E(g)$Invested.Amount.in.EUR - min(E(g)$Invested.Amount.in.EUR))) / (max(E(g)$Invested.Amount.in.EUR)-min(E(g)$Invested.Amount.in.EUR)))+0.2)
```

and it works smoothly!